# Use keystore in SOAPUI Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, security, soapui, keystore

Using the SOAPUI Eclipse project, how do I specify the keystore to be used by a SOAP project? The URL: http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html shows how it is done for the standalone SOAPUI. I searched as much as I could but couldn't figure out a way to do something similar with the plugin.

Thanks.

John.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is under: `Window` --> `Preferences` --> `soapUi` --> `SSL Settings`

Similar to how it is in `SoapUI` itself

[image]